# How to pass user token across pytest API tests

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to design pytest automation suite to rest REST APIs

In **conftest.py** I have:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--env", action="store", help="accepting dev,qa,stage")

def pytest_configure(config):
    global base_path,execution_path,users,user_alpha,user_beta,user_gamma,psw_alpha,psw_beta,psw_gamma

    cfg=ConfigParser()
    cfg.read('config.ini') 

    base_path = cfg.get('base', 'path')

    if config.getoption('env') in ['qa','stage','dev']:
        environ = config.getoption('env')
        execution_path = base_path.format(env=environ)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def base():
    global execution_path
    return execution_path

def get_user():
    global execution_path,users

    cfg=ConfigParser()
    cfg.read('config.ini')

    user1 = cfg.get('users','user1')
    psw_user1 = cfg.get('users','psw.user1')

    user2 = cfg.get('users','user.user2')
    psw_user2 = cfg.get('users','psw.user2')

    user3 = cfg.get('users','user.user3')
    psw_user3 = cfg.get('users','psw.user3')

    users = [(user1, psw_user1,user1_token), (user2, psw_user2,user2_token), (user3, psw_user3,user3_token)]

    return users

@pytest.fixture(params=get_user(),scope='session', ids=['user1','user2','user3'])
def return_user(request):
    return request.param
```

in **test_module.py**:

```
def test_function1(base, return_user):
    pass

def test_function2(base, return_user):
    pass
```

**output**

```
test_upload.py::test_pass4[user1] PASSED                                [ 16%]
test_upload.py::test_pass5[user1] PASSED                                [ 33%]
test_upload.py::test_pass4[user2] PASSED                                [ 50%]
test_upload.py::test_pass5[user2] PASSED                                [ 66%]
test_upload.py::test_pass4[user3] PASSED                                [ 83%]
test_upload.py::test_pass5[user3] PASSED                                [100%]
```

Creating tokens can be accomplished with pytest_configure(metafunc). However with pytest_configure pytest runs test_pass4 for each user, then begins test_pass5 for each and thus generating a new token for every test. I'd like to have the same token for all tests in the same module for same user.

To get the token I need command line argument passed so that I can format the execution_path with env variable passed in command line. I can accomplish this by def get_user(config) to access env. However @pytest.fixture(params=get_user(config)) doesn't recognize config. Or I don't have other parameters to pass in get_user().

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**: I was able to access command line arguments inside the fixture with `pytest.config.getoption('env'))` and then do necessary transformation inside the fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(params=get_user(),scope='session', ids=['user1','user2','user3'])
def return_user(request):
    cfg=ConfigParser()
    cfg.read('config.ini') 

    base_path = cfg.get('base', 'path')
    base_path = base_path.format(env=request.config.getoption('env'))

    user = #payload to login user  
    user.token = #code to get token

    temp = request.param
    temp.append(user.token)
    return temp
```